# How to change the recyclerview first row layout?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to add different layout for the first row, how can i set it up?

Adapter class:
This is the normal, all row equals:

```
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
inflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_trends, parent, false));
}
```

And what to change in the OnBindViewHolder method?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First you need to override `getItemViewType`. Return itemType according to your requirements.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0) return 1;
    else return 2;
}
```

then in `onCreateViewHolder` inflate your different layout according to your viewType.

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == 1) {
        // inflate your first item layout & return that viewHolder
    } else {
        // inflate your second item layout & return that viewHolder
    }
}
```

Comment: nice to hear that.. :)