# How to get ViewHolder of specific Item of Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Is there a way to get the `ViewHolder` of specific Item of recyclerview base on given position only?

Something like `getViewHolder(position);`.

```
public MyViewHolder getViewHolder(int position){
    MyViewHolder holder = null;
    /**
        Find ViewHolder here...
            If Found initialize the holder..
                holder = ?
    **/
    return holder;
}
```

This function is in my Adapter class, I'm looking for a way to get the `ViewHolder` of an Item so I can change the value of one of my view of my custom item `eg. holder.setText("Hello World");`, I'm stock, I can't find a way to do that, I tried to search but none of them help me.

Anyone?

Comment: this might help you for position specific viewholder : http://stackoverflow.com/a/40240599/1263362

Comment: @Sayem - Thank you for the link, but can you please explain how it helps my problem? Thank You.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve after you get the view holder?

Comment: @HendraWD - Hi! this what I want to achieve: I have a countdown timer that runs in the background, every Items has a different countdown timer and duration, `When I close and reopen the application, the Texview that I want to show the duration is no longer updating`, so I'm guessing that I can solve it with `Every seconds that count by the timer, Call the function in my adapter class that find the ViewHolder base on the given position, if it is found then set the textview with that holder of the current duration.` eg. `theFoundHolder.textviewDuration.setText("00:00:00")`.

Comment: @Sayem - Absolutely yes, that's what I'm trying to do. I don't know how can I possible update the the list item from my background timer(`I am using Handler post delay`) so that it will continue updating the list item from reopening the application.

Comment: did you try adapter.notifyItemChanged(position); this function will call onBindViewHolder in which you can update your item. Actually it is bit more difficult with your current given code. give some more code what you have written.

Comment: @Sayem - I got an Idea, thank you for your comment, this is what I will try `1: on every seconds of timer, find the position of items base on TAG of view`, `2: Update the Data of that item base on position e.g. dataModel.get(position).setDuration(theCurrentDurationOfTime)`, `3: notifyItemChanged(position);`.  let me update you if it works later. Thanks!

Comment: yes.. thats the way. you will update your data model. tell your adapter that what is changed. then adapter will update your view.

Comment: @Polar Sorry for late response. Yes i agree with your logic there, because if you change the view directly, it will not accurate, and will be changed back when you scroll your RecyclerView, because the RecyclerView will change the data back on `onBindViewHolder` callback when you set the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how ViewHolder works. ViewHolder is just a holder of layout that you made. ViewHolder is automatically re-use-able, so if you have 100 items, android will not create 100 ViewHolders, instead of just some ViewHolders that visible on the screen. If you scroll the RecyclerView, the ViewHolder of non-visible item will be re-used. You just need to change the data on the ViewHolder that passed automatically on method `onBindViewHolder`

Here is the example

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textViewTitle.setText(data.get(position).title);
    holder.textViewContent.setText(data.get(position).content);

    Context context = holder.button.getContext();    
    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "you clicked the button!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Edit: To make it more clear, what you should do is change the specific data from your adapter, for example you can create a method in your adapter like this

```
public void changeItem(int position, ItemModel newItemModel){
    mItemModelList.remove(position);
    mItemModelList.add(position, newItemModel);
}
```

then call `notifyItemChanged(int position)` of your adapter.

Comment: Here i just want to make sure that people will not do a bad practice in Android. So before you downvote, you should understand the problem of the asker and create a better approach.

Comment: `holder.button.setOnClickListener` in my answer isn't really best practice, but can be used to set `onClickListener` to a `View`. The best practice is to set `onClickListener` once when creating `ViewHolder`, then use `getAdapterPosition()` to determine the click position, so you can retrieve the correct data from the position.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (your_recyclerview != null) {
        val viewholder = your_recyclerview .findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(your positions)
        if (viewholder != null){
            adapter.pausePlayer(viewholder as FeedPostDetailCommentAdapter.FeedDetailViewHolder)
        }
    }
```

Comment: thats is my metho name in may recyclerview adapter

Answer (score -1):

```
public static RecyclerView.ViewHolder getViewHolder(View view) {
    RecyclerView rv = getParentRecyclerView(view);
    View rvChild = getParentViewHolderItemView(view);

    if (rv != null && rvChild != null) {
        return rv.getChildViewHolder(rvChild);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you.
For your reference you can visit this link as well.

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView&method=getChildViewHolder

Comment: Can't resolve method `getParentRecyclerView` and `getParentViewHolderItemView`. And base on your code how can I tell that the return viewHolder is the one I am looking for?

Comment: You are passing view in the method to get respected view holder.

Comment: but the `getParentRecyclerView` and `getParentViewHolderItemView` is cannot resolve.

Comment: Please try findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(int position) as in docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is **yes**.

But the price you pay for forcing *ViewHolder* creation is to programmatically scroll to the desired position then capture it via callback delivered from a custom scroll listener.

Should take about 10 minutes to implement the code described in my answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59174061/2376004).