# Getting visible and Non-visible items from RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

This simple code below ONLY gets all visible items, but I need to get all items (both Visible and non-visible).

Is this possible to get completely all Items and how?

```
// This gets only visible items
final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(index);

// Same as this
final View child = recyclerView.getChildAt(index);
final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = recyclerView.getChildViewHolder(child);
```

I am also interested in any work around this. If possible.

Comment: Are you aware that `RecyclerView` reuses `ViewHolder`s as you scroll? Even if your list has 5000+ items there will be only enough `ViewHolder`s to fit your view port.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question was first asked [3 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40602095).

On first view, as **Pawel** points out, it seems that you are asking for the **impossible**, because unless the View of interest is actually visible then the corresponding ViewHolder may or may not exist - and there is apparently no native method to force it's creation.

My requirement was for the visibility and highlighting of any item in the dataset to be **determined remotely**!

Strategy for achieving this was to force *ViewHolder* creation by scrolling to the desired item then returning the newly-created ViewHolder via callback.

The solution is non-trivial but I trust the code is well documented. I suggest you copy the static methods and interface into a utility class and deploy them as per the dummy *exampleOfUse()* method. If you cannot use them ***as is***, please let me know.

I have included the 2 scroll-related methods for completeness only. Ignore my logger: **lg()**

Bear in mind that pre-scrolling to the desired item is the price you pay for getting to the ViewHolder - and therefore the ability to issue **notifyItemChanged()**. [ Suited me, but maybe not everyone. ]

```
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  These 3 static methods provide:
//      (A) Smooth or direct scrolling for any RecyclerView. [ ScrollTo() ]
//      (B) A technique for obtaining the ViewHolder of any item (visible or otherwise).
//          [ Achieved via callback when scroll to desired position has completed. ]
//          [ Why: (e.g.) To highlight an externally selected (or any) RecyclerView item ]
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/** Sample method of use */
public void dummyExampleOfUse(RecyclerView rv, int pos) {
    getAnyViewHolder(rv, pos, true, new GetAnyViewHolder() {
        @Override
        public void scrollForViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh, int pos) {
            if (vh==null) lg("Failed!!!");      // <-- Your logger
            //else ((YourViewHolder)vh).yourViewHolderMethod(pos);
            // yourViewHolderMethod would typically issue notifyItemChanged(pos);
        }
    });
}

/** Interface to receive requested ViewHolder */
public interface GetAnyViewHolder {
    void scrollForViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh, int pos);
}

/** RecyclerView scroll with callback returning desired ViewHolder */
public static boolean getAnyViewHolder(RecyclerView rv, int pos, boolean smooth, GetAnyViewHolder cb) {
    if (rv==null) return false;
    if (rv.getAdapter() == null) return false;
    if (rv.getAdapter().getItemCount() < 1) return false;
    if (pos <0 || pos > rv.getAdapter().getItemCount()-1) return false;
    rv.addOnScrollListener(new MPA_SL(rv, cb, pos));
    scrollTo(rv, pos, smooth, null);       // Note user-specified scroll action!
    return true;
}

/** Custom Scroll listener needed for 'getAnyViewHolder()' */
private static class MPA_SL extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
    RecyclerView rv; GetAnyViewHolder gavh; int pos;
    MPA_SL( RecyclerView rv,GetAnyViewHolder gavh, int pos ) {  // Constructor
        this.rv = rv; this.gavh = gavh; this.pos = pos;}
    @Override public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView rv, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(rv, newState);
        lg(format("Scroll state: %d", newState));
        if(newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh = rv.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(pos);
            gavh.scrollForViewHolder(vh, pos);      // Notify user
            rv.removeOnScrollListener(this);        // Self-destruct
        }
    }
}

/** Scroll according to speed */
public static void scrollTo(RecyclerView rv, int os, boolean smooth, TextView tv) {
    try {
        if (smooth) { smoothScroll(rv, os); }
        else { rv.scrollToPosition(os); }
    } catch ( IllegalArgumentException ile) {
        if (tv==null) {
            lg(format("Scroll error: %s", ile.getMessage()));
            return;
        }
        String msg = tv.getText().toString() + " ";
        msg += ile.getMessage();
        tv.setText(msg);
    }
}

/** Smoothly scroll to specified position at 1/4 speed */
private static void smoothScroll(RecyclerView rv, int position) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    RecyclerView.SmoothScroller smoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(gc()) {
        @Override protected int getVerticalSnapPreference() {
            return LinearSmoothScroller.SNAP_TO_START;
        }
        @Override protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel(DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
            float millesecondsPerPixel = super.calculateSpeedPerPixel(displayMetrics);
            return millesecondsPerPixel * 4;
        }
    };
    smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
    rv.getLayoutManager().startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
}
```

Good luck!